Switch to new MegaMenu for theme
I have recently installed Magento 2.4 and have purchased and installed the fastest theme.
I have created child themes from my favorite version, fastest-outdoor. but for the life of me I can't figure out how to set the child themes to use a specific megamenu created through the codazon>Create new megamenu.
I have scoured the magento admin and am starting to think this change needs to be done in code.. hopefully someone can chime in before I go down an uneccessary rabbit-hole.
How is linking a megamenu to a theme done for fastest?
